# What does it mean "to be proficient in Shas and Poskim" as said about Talmidi Chachamim?

Tags: torah-study, commentaries, rabbis

One constantly reads in biographies about Gedolim or at a friend's siyum HaShas that mention how the talmid chacham or guy is a bucky and a maeivin in Shas and poskim. See example [in this Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F) about HaRav Refael Ahron Ben Shimon, in the first few sentences: בן שמעון נולד ברבאט שבמרוקו, לאביו הרב דוד בן שמעון ולאמו רחל. בשנת 1854 עלה לארץ ישראל ביחד עם אביו. בילדותו קיבל חינוך מסורתי והצטיין בידיעותיו בתלמוד ופוסקים.

What does it mean to be bucky in Shas and poskim? Does it include knowing the:

Klallim and concepts?

Interconnected sugyot from different mesachtos?

Basic shakal v'taraya on every amud baal peh, as in knowing every word verbatim as mentioned to being a "Shas Yid?"

What is the geder of "poskim?"

4a. Does this include knowing all the mefarshim: Rashi, Tosfos, Rishonim, Achronim all the way to halacha l'maaseh in modern poskim?

4b. Does that also mean Baal Peh or the general concepts?

4c. What about the different variations of how you can read and interpret (bavern) the concepts? Is part of being a bucky in that regard include knowing the variations word-for-word or just conceptual memorization suffices?

4d. Which poskim do we refer to? Rambam, Rif, Rosh?

4e. Do we include Tur, Shulchan Aruch, and all of their mefarshim/Nosei Kelim?

4f. What about modern Poskim and Shu"t of different Rabanim?

4g. Is it all of the above?

What does it mean when one says that he "knows Shas and poskim?" I know that each Jew has a different part in Torah, and assume that the level of an average but hardworking 21-year-old bachur who just finished Shas isn't going to be the same as Saar HaTorah, Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky. Even with the understanding that each Jew has a different chelek and level in Torah, it still seems unclear what is included in this bukiyus?

Still, there seems to be a well-established status quo continuously referred to that is not clear what defines "bucky in Shas and poskim."

**Please provide sources for your answers.**

Comment: I very much disagree with the "If I learn *shas baal peh* then I will be the *gadol ha'dor*" concept, if that is what you mean?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard definition as opposed to a separate one used by each person who uses the term.

Comment: There are many many more so called geonim today than ever existed in bovel. A bokee in shas today is no more than what is termed chamor nosai seforim.

Comment: The GRAPKE, definitely not what I meant.

Comment: msh210, that is the gist of what I am getting the more I look into the matter.

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2020/12/rabbi-steinman-and-the-messiah-part-2/ see #3 (quiz questions about Rashi saying someone was a baki in Shas)

Comment: IMHO, as with many other qualities, like "Ayn Tovah" or "Na'im Halichot", Baki in Shas is not quantitative. THere's no formal Halachic definition of "Rabbi" in Judaism, no tests or exams. It's the community that decides if one is proficient enough or not.

Comment: So the fact that there is no concrete source found yet closes this article for being "opinion-based?" In that case, if I learned one meseches, it's my opinion to call myself a bucky in Shas? I don't think it's totally opinion-based; there must be some k'lallim. I think the moderation to close the question is a bit hasty. But perhaps that's "opinion-based."